# Getting error while trying to start webview Activity with multiple URLs

Tags: android, url, webview

I am trying to create a simple app with webview. I want to load multiple urls in a single webview with onclicklistener.

I have a main view, in that I have 4 buttons. if I click a button, it will open its assigned url in same webview.
but when I am trying in emulator, it is getting stopped. I don't know what's wrong with this code.
here is my code.

```
package com.shiraz.shirazdesigner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button aas, fcbk, twtr, ytb;
WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    aas = (Button)findViewById(R.id.aasBtn);
    fcbk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fbBtn);
    twtr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.twtrBtn);
    ytb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ytBtn);
    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    aas.setOnClickListener(this);
    fcbk.setOnClickListener(this);
    twtr.setOnClickListener(this);
    ytb.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.aasBtn:
            webview.loadUrl("http://www.shirazdesigner.com");
            Intent aasint = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Webview.class);
            startActivity(aasint);
            break;
        case R.id.fbBtn:
            webview.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/shiraz.designer");
            Intent fbint = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Webview.class);
            startActivity(fbint);
            break;
        case R.id.twtrBtn:
            webview.loadUrl("http://www.twitter.com/shirazdesigner");
            Intent twtrInt = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Webview.class);
            startActivity(twtrInt);
            break;
        case R.id.ytBtn:
            webview.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/shirazdesigner");
            Intent ytInt = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Webview.class);
            startActivity(ytInt);               
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Here is manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.shiraz.shirazdesigner"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.shiraz.shirazdesigner.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.shiraz.shirazdesigner.Webview"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are launching a new activity (Webview).
In this case,

```
webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

will return null because this widget is in the layout of the Webview activity that is launched by startActivity() .
And if you don't have a Webview widget in the first activity ( MainActivity ), this following line will cause an error.

```
webview.loadUrl("http://www.shirazdesigner.com");
```

**You can send the URL from Main Activity to WebView Activity :**

```
Intent fbint = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Webview.class);
fbint.putExtra("url", "http://www.fsdfsdgfsdgsdgsd.com")
startActivity(fbint);
```

**And in your WebView activity, you will get it and assign it to the WebView widget**

```
String theUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webview.loadUrl(theUrl );
```